# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on simple program that defines class in header file and implementation file

Tags: c++, g++

I'm brushing up on C++ and running into this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GradeBook::getCourseName()", referenced from:
      _main in gbDriver-a5418c.o
  "GradeBook::GradeBook(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in gbDriver-a5418c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my driver file (named `gbDriver.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  GradeBook gradeBook1( "CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming" );
  GradeBook gradeBook2( "CS102 Data Structures in C++" );

  cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName() << "\ngradeBook2 created for course: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName() << endl;
}
```

Here's my header file where I define the class (and interface) (named `Gradebook.h`):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
public:
  GradeBook( string );
  void setCourseName( string );
  string getCourseName();
  void displayMessage();
private:
  string courseName;
};
```

Here's the file in which I implement the GradeBook class member functions (named `GradeBook.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook( string name )
{
   setCourseName( name );
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName( string name )
{
  courseName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
  return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
  cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
}
```

I'm running into the aforementioned error upon attempting to compile by running: `g++ gbDriver.cpp`. What's going on?

I know probably is a simple matter but I can't figure it out and it's driving me nuts. It doesn't seem to have to do with my compiler, so I'm guessing my code is wrong somewhere.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show exactly the compilation command...

Comment: Thanks Basile. from the directory that houses all three files: `g++ gbDriver.cpp`

Comment: You have to list all the `.cpp` files you want compiled.

Comment: ahhh gotcha! rookie mistake, ok. so the issue was simply running: `g++ gbDriver.cpp` where instead I should have been running `g++ gbDriver.cpp GradeBook.cpp`. Sweet, thanks for the help @kfsone!

Comment: Learn about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make). Always compile with all warnings & debug info `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ compiler doesn't have any way of knowing that it is supposed to compile GradeBook.cpp to produce symbols, or to join it with gbDriver.cpp - you are only telling it to compile gbDriver.cpp.

If you want to combine gbDriver.cpp and GradeBook.cpp into an executable called "gradebook.exe" use the command:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o gradebook.exe gbDriver.cpp GradeBook.cpp
```

the `.exe` suffix isn't very unixy but I sometimes find it helpful, a more unixy variant of this would be:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o gradebook gbDriver.cpp GradeBook.cpp
```

or if you just want to compile all the .cpp files in the current directory together:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o gradebook *.cpp
```

The arguments I'm adding here:

```
-Wall
    Shows many more warnings that might affect how your program works,
-g
    Includes debugging symbols in the output to make it easier to debug
-o filename
    Specifies the output filename
```